# MySQL Query Exception calling "Fill" with "2" argument(s) from Powershell v4

Tags: mysql, powershell

Trying to execute a MySql query from Powershell ver 4, I get this error:

```
Could not run MySQL Query Exception calling "Fill" with "2" argument(s): "Fatal error encountered during command execution."
```

Here's the SQL I'm trying from Powershell.  The SQL is in variable $updateReportQuery:

```
$updateReportQuery = "call count_changed_mark(@count_changed_mark);"
MySQLQuery -ConnectionString $connection -query $updateReportQuery
```

For reference, here is a snippet from the MySQLQuery function used with other queries no problem:

```
# Run MySQL Querys
Write-Verbose "Run MySQL Querys"
$command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($query, $connection)
$dataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($command)
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$recordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
$dataSet.Tables["data"] | Format-Table
return $dataSet.Tables[“data”] #returns response as an object
```

When I output the SQL from the function to write-host then copy/paste the SQL in a SQL console, it runs fine.  I only get the error from Powershell.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the user variable.  Must add `Allow User Variables=True;` to connection string.

Example:

```
$connection = "Server=localhost;Uid=youruserid;Pwd=yourpassword;database=yourdatabase;Allow User Variables=True;"
```